# How to hide a div if it overlaps another div

Tags: javascript, css, html, hide, overlap

Is this CSS or javascript? I just need the div to change to display:none if it comes within say 20px of another div. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this? It is possible however depending on why you wan to there may be a better alternative.

Comment: Yes it is so that if the user makes their browser window small my site does not look crowded

Comment: It will probably look better if you just set a min width so a scroll bar appears when it gets too small then. (e.g. how SO does it :P)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps

```
//Listen to the event that will be triggered on window resize:
window.onresize = function(event) 
{
    // test if one element overlaps another
    if($('#div1').overlaps('#div2'))
    {
        //Do stuff, like hide one of the overlapping divs
        $('#div1').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler that gets fired when the window is resized. You could do this with javascript or jquery. jquery makes it easy:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
var h=$(window).height();
var w=$(window).width();

if(h<400 && w < 300){
 //hide divs
 $('#yourdivid1').hide();
}


}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> Yes it is so that if the user makes their browser window small my site
>   does not look crowded

***Instead of answering the question you asked, Here's an answer to the question you didn't ask:***

> How to resize/position/cssify page elements based on browser size?

There is a new-ish application of css and javascript called [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). Responsive Design allows you to specify different css rules to apply based on different elements. For a great example of this technique, resize your browser around on [The Boston Globe](http://www.bostonglobe.com/)'s website. They just integrated this technique sometime this week.

Here's an example of the css that would implement this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  .content {
    float: left;
  }

  .social_icons {
    display: none
  }

  // and so on...

}
```

example from http://thinkvitamin.com/design/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design/

Here is a [boilerplate](http://thatcoolguy.github.com/gridless-boilerplate/) to get you going.

Comment: nice, didn't know this could be done with css. is this cross browser?

Comment: Sure is. Here's a boilerplate http://thatcoolguy.github.com/gridless-boilerplate/